# Mod rewrite https to http but not /administrator/

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla

I have a joomla installation on a domain where i have https.
Now i want `www.domain.com/administrator` uses https, but all ohter urls should use http instead of https.

At moment i have this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

This will redirect all https to http. it works.
But how can i exclude the

> www.domain.com/administrator

url?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why? You're going backwards. Use HTTPS everywhere. The CPU cost isn't an issue there days.

Comment: I have good positions on google with this site. I readed about, that a change from http to https could harm my positions on google. I want to prevent this.

Comment: Changing from HTTP to HTTPS will **benefit** your site on Google. See [here](http://searchengineland.com/google-want-to-switch-to-https-go-ahead-140068) and [here](http://searchengineland.com/google-starts-giving-ranking-boost-secure-httpsssl-sites-199446). In general, things that are good for users are not bad for your search engine ranking.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want your administrator URL to use `https://`, then this is a default Joomla parameter.

In the Joomla backend, go to:

**Global Configuration** >> **Server**

and set the **Force SSL** to **Administrator Only**

Comment: Yes, this i did alredy. But my problem is, that my site now is accessible through http AND https.
Maybe it is no problem, bu it could be double content for google. And i want to prevent this.

Comment: Google does not care about your protocol when looking at duplicate content, it only cares about the uri.  The protocol is not part of the uri and as said above https helps you anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to achieve that with your htaccess, you can put this code into it

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/administrator
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/administrator
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```